# Why do x86 FP compares set CF like unsigned integers, instead of using signed conditions?

Tags: assembly, x86, sse, sse2, x87

The following documentation is provided in the Intel Instruction Reference for the `COMISD` instruction:

> Compares the double-precision floating-point values in the low
>   quadwords of operand 1 (first operand) and operand 2 (second operand),
>   and sets the `ZF`, `PF`, and `CF` flags in the EFLAGS register according to
>   the result (unordered, greater than, less than, or equal).

The `CF`'s flag point is not really clear here since it is related to arithmetic operations on unsigned integers. By contrast, the documentation is concerned about floating point which are signed by definition. I ran a few experiments, like

```
mov rax, 0x123
movq xmm0, rax

mov rax, 0x124
movq xmm1, rax

ucomisd xmm0, xmm1 ;CF is set here like if
                    ;we would compare uints 0x123 and 0x124
```

So the instruction treats the operands as unsigned integers when setting Carry Flag up while the operands are double-precision floating points?

To me it looks a bit strange.

Comment: Have you taken a look at what actual double values those values represent?

Comment: The reason is probably because mapping it to signed would need both `SF` and `OF` so that would be more complicated.

Comment: @Jester: No, you could get that cheaply by clearing OF and just setting SF, or vice versa.  The main reason is for compat with how `fcom` / `fstsw` / `sahf` sets FLAGS from the FP status word, same as `fcomi`.  It's unfortunate that SSE FP compares don't also set OF/SF in a way that lets you distinguish `>`, `<`, and `==`from unordered without checking PF separately

Comment: You do want to set `SF` as expected otherwise people would still complain that it doesn't work like it does for integers. Not sure about `OF`.

Comment: `[u]comis[sd]` unconditionally clears OF and SF.  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/comisd.  It *doesn't* work like integer `cmp`.

Comment: Right. That is the reason for the complaint, the way I read it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Modern x86 SSE/AVX scalar FP compares set EFLAGS the same way as original 8086 + 8087

`fcom` + `fstsw ax` <sup>1</sup> + `sahf`.**

- [`fcom`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/fcom:fcomp:fcompp) since 8086
- [`fcomi`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/fcomi:fcomip:fucomi:fucomip) new in PPro, sets EFLAGS directly
- [`[u]comis[sd]`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/comisd) new in SSE/SSE2, also sets EFLAGS directly.

After ruling out "unordered", the "above" (`>`), "below" (`<`), and "equal" (`==`) conditions for `jcc`/`setcc`/`cmovcc`/`fcmovcc` all have the appropriate semantic meaning.  (And combinations of them like `jae`.)

Keeping the flag-setting the same made it easier for programmers and compiler-developers to drop in scalar SSE code, in place of scalar x87 code, without having to redo any logic about which way unordered compares (PF=ZF=CF=1) would go.  Tricks like `ja` (CF==0) being taken only for `>` (not for unordered, equal, or below) still work identically with the same branches.

See http://www.ray.masmcode.com/tutorial/fpuchap7.htm for x87 FP comparisons.  Also related: [x86 assembler: floating point compare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057501/x86-assembler-floating-point-compare) for more about flag-setting and how you can sometimes get away without a `jp` to rule out the unordered case.

Note that the packed-compare instructions like [`cmppd`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cmppd) and `cmpsd` that produce a mask still use `lt` for less than in the names of their comparison predicates.  (Since AVX, there are more detailed predicate names like `LT_OQ` (QNaN isn't an exception) vs. `LT_OS` (QNaN has its usual effect) vs. `NLT_US` (Unordered: also true when the comparison is unordered).  Since they have to produce a 0/1 result from each packed comparison, those SIMD compare instructions need a single predicate to check as well as just doing a compare.

---

Also, unsigned conditions (CF) allow more optimizations. So changing to signed conditions would have been worse.

**x86 has more instructions that do things with CF than with any other flag**.  For example, you can do `tmp += (x > 10)` with `ucomisd` / `adc eax, 0`.  If SSE/SSE2 had decided to set SF (and clearing OF), you'd need `sets` or other `setcc` to feed an `add` instruction.

---

#### Why did x87 use ja/jbe instead of jg/jle?

`OF` is outside the low 8 bits of FLAGS so `sahf` can't set it.  And `popf` to set the whole FLAGS register could set or clear other non-condition FLAGS like `IF` (interrupts enabled) or `TF` (single-step trap after every instruction).  Plus being generally less convenient to use because of modifying SP.

Signed flag-conditions are based on `SF!=OF` or `SF==OF`, so it was impossible for the original 8086 FP branching mechanism to have used signed conditions.  Instead, they lined up the C0, C2, and C3 bits in the FP status word with CF, PF, and ZF in FLAGS.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16227582/fcom-floating-point-comparison-fails/16228425#16228425) has an ASCII-art diagram.

---

**Footnote 1**: Actually `fstsw ax` was new in 286, according to [NASM's appendix B](https://nasm.us/doc/nasmdocb.html#section-B.1.2).  In *actual* 8086+8087 code, you'd use something like `fstsw [bp-2]` / `mov ax, [bp-2]` / `sahf` or whatever scratch space you wanted to use.

---

> So the instruction treats the operands as unsigned integers

**No, definitely not**.  They are interpreted as sign/magnitude IEEE `binary64` FP bit-patterns.

Unsigned integer comparison would give a different result for negative floating point numbers:  High bit set => higher unsigned integer, but represents a negative FP value.

With the high bit set, `0x8...4` is unsigned-integer above `0x8...3`, but as an FP bit pattern, it represents a more-negative (lower) number.

**Forget about the "unsigned" association of the "above" / "below" conditions when using them for FP.**  That's just what x86 calls the conditions that test the carry flag.

**FP comparisons set the carry flag by a completely different mechanism than actual integer subtraction.**

Comment: So since `fcomi` instruction operates on FPU stack comparing ST0 with `STi` and sets `CF` __iff__ `ST0 < STi` it is possible to conclude that the corresponding `sse` instructions set `CF` __iff__ the destination operand is less then the source operand.  I checked that on some examples and it was true.

Comment: @St.Antario: yes, "above" and "below", and "equal" all have the expected semantic meaning after an FP compare, just no implication of unsigned.

Comment: @InstructionPointer : thanks for the edits.  I don't always take the time to go back and proof-read the whole answer so I do sometimes end up with a stray phrase or broken grammar from moving stuff around or rephrasing during editing.

Comment: @PeterCordes I have discovered "submitting edits" as a very useful part of my learning process. I do not think I am a naturally intelligent person, I have to see the same information restated and shown in a variety of ways before I really internalize it, editing just helps me do that. Plus I imagine I improve the overall quality of the site for future learners.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197126/discussion-between-instruction-pointer-and-peter-cordes).

Answer (score 3):

You should look at the "Operation" section found lower on the page.  To summarize:

- `PF` is set when unordered, clear if ordered
- `ZF` is set if zero or unordered, clear if nonzero
- `CF` is set if less than or unordered, clear if greater than

And yes, the bit-patterns are interpreted as IEEE 754 `binary64` [double-precision floating point numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).

`0x123` and `0x124` are the bit-patterns for positive sub-normal values very close to `0.0`.  If DAZ was set in MXCSR, it would be interepreted as exactly `0.0`.  But by default subnormals are handled as per IEEE754.

---

If you want to test that it's really a sign/magnitude FP compare, instead of an unsigned integer compare, test with negative FP values.  (High bit set => higher unsigned integer, but represents a more-negative lower FP value).

Fun fact: other than the sign bit, the biased-exponent representation that IEEE FP uses *does* make it possible to compare the integer bit-patterns of FP numbers.  And to implement `nextafter` as an integer increment of the bit-pattern, after checking the sign to figure out whether to add `+1` or `-1`.