# _mm_comieq_ss difference between Clang and GCC

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, simd, sse

I have some SIMD code that's checking for equality between vars but I'm getting different results between GCC and clang when NaNs are involved:

```
bool equal(__m128 a, __m128 b){
    return _mm_comieq_ss(a,b) == 1;
}

int main()
{
    __m128 a, b, c;

    a = _mm_set_ss(std::numeric_limits<float>::quiet_NaN());
    b = _mm_set_ss(1.0f);
    c = _mm_set_ss(1.0f);
    
    std::cout << "comieq(a,b):" << equal(a,b) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "comieq(b,a):" << equal(b,a) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "comieq(b,c):" << equal(b,c) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "comieq(a,a):" << equal(a,a) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Clang and GCC return different values:

```
gcc:
comieq(a,b):1
comieq(b,a):1
comieq(b,c):1
comieq(a,a):1

clang:
comieq(a,b):0
comieq(b,a):0
comieq(b,c):1
comieq(a,a):0
```

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening?  I just want to check if two regs are equal or not; is there an alternative way to do this that's consistent?

godbolt: [https://godbolt.org/z/ETKenE45f](https://godbolt.org/z/o6GMMKxre)

Comment: @AdrianMole: Intel's documentation for the intrinsic specifies the behaviour that clang implements: act like an IEEE `==` compare, false if the comparison is unordered.  (https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#techs=MMX,SSE_ALL,AVX_ALL,Other&ig_expand=6243,519,365,365,164,24,1424,1424&text=comiss).  But GCC's asm only checks the ZF result of `comiss` / `ucomiss`, ignoring PF, so it ends up treating unordered as equal.  (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/comiss).  This is a GCC bug, other than intentional bug-compatibility with old compilers, not current docs.

Comment: @AdrianMole: Your answer seems complete enough, now, with that quote from the LLVM devs explaining why GCC still gets it wrong, because apparently ICC also did historically.  I didn't know that history when I first commented, and you've edited to include my update, so it also covers why Clang changed to get it right.  BTW, a more efficient implementation in asm would be `cmpeqss xmm,xmm` / `movd eax, xmm` instead of integer `setcc` on both ZF and PF.  (Except with `-ffast-math`, then `comiss` / checking ZF wins.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The different handling of return values when comparing `NaN` values was *specifically* changed in Clang 3.9.0. [Related Link](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/issues/4435).

Although one would expect *intrinsic* functions to be just that – intrinsic to the CPU and *not* compiler-dependent, [the `comiss` instruction](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/comiss) produces a result in multiple bits of FLAGS.  Different intrinsics check different predicates to define a single boolean return value; in asm it would be up to the programmer to use a combination of instructions like `je`, `jb`, and/or `jp` or `setcc` / `cmovcc` to use the compare result.

What is happening here is that GCC is checking *only* the `ZF` (zero flag) value, whereas Clang is also (correctly) checking the `PF` ('parity' flag: set if the comparison is unordered, i.e. one of the inputs is `NaN`.  This [matches the way integer FLAGS were](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57188286/why-do-x86-fp-compares-set-cf-like-unsigned-integers-instead-of-using-signed-co) set by P6 x87 `fcomi`, in turn matching older x87 `fcom` / `fstsw ax` / `sahf`).

I shall offer a *short* quotation from the discussion linked above, which may shed some light on the reasoning behind the decision made by the LLVM (clang) team:

> In Clang 3.8.0 and before, comparing two scalars of which at least one
> is a NaN would return 1. This is also the behavior that GCC, Visual
> Studio, and our current Emscripten code implements. This behavior is
> unintuitive in the sense that comparing NaNs in floats have the
> opposite tradition in IEEE-754, i.e. "nothing is equal to a NaN".
>
> Intel is the original author of these intrinsics, and it must be
> admitted that these functions have long suffered from poor
> documentation. Intel doesn't spec in detail how these intrinsics
> should work with respect to NaNs
> (https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/514308), but presumably the
> reference implementation in their own compiler was held as the ground
> truth. The behavior that GCC, VS and Clang <= 3.8 each follow likely
> comes from adhering to the original code as implemented in Intel's
> compilers, where _mm_comieq_ss is implemented to perform the COMISS
> instruction and return the resulting zero flag (ZF) register state as
> the output int value of the intrinsic function. The COMISS instruction
> itself is though well documented since it's part of the ISA, and is
> shown e.g. at
> http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_44.html. This shows
> the origin of the unexpected NaN behavior, since the zero flag is set
> if the comparison is equal, or if the comparison result is unordered,
> i.e. at least one of the registers is a NaN.

---

Following the comment from Peter Cordes, it is now clear that the (modified) clang behaviour is *correct* and the "poor documentation" from Intel referred to in the above citation has been corrected. The [Intel documentation for `_mm_comieq_ss`](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#techs=MMX,SSE_ALL,AVX_ALL,Other&ig_expand=6243,519,365,365,164,24,1424,1424&text=comiss) now makes it clear that any `NaN` value present should yield a return value of zero:

> ##### Operation
>
> `RETURN ( a[31:0] != NaN AND b[31:0] != NaN AND a[31:0] == b[31:0] ) ? 1 : 0`

Comment: That comment is out of date; the current Intel intrinsics guide *does* detail the fact that NaNs make the `eq` intrinsic predicate false.  `RETURN ( a[31:0] != NaN AND b[31:0] != NaN AND a[31:0] == b[31:0] ) ? 1 : 0`.  https://godbolt.org/z/zTn8aj84v shows ICC 16.0.3 follow that documented behaviour, although ICC13 does only check ZF like they discuss in that 2016 comment.  I commented on the LLVM issue with an update (https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/issues/4435#issuecomment-1480546251)

Comment: found this on gcc bug tracker: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=98612 
says will be fixed after intrinsics guide updated, but not good round to it yet...

Comment: did a bit more searching, seems this is fixed in gcc 13+ 
https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=106113

godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/qP891ceGG